# dropzone $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I try to submit a form with some dropzone-added files and additional fields.

I don´t want those dropzone Ajax Features, because i want to add some information by additional inputs.

So, at least a very simple Submit-Form with multiple Files, which gets processed **after** pressing the submit button.
So far, the client side works fine, but when I submit the form, $_FILES is empty! Why?
What I got so far:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST))
{
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
    exit;
}
?>

<form id="smart-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php">

    <div class="form-body">

        <div class="section">
            <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
                <h3 class="dz-drop-title"> Drop files here or </h3>
                <p class="dz-clicker"> <span> Browse File </span> </p>
                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end section -->

    </div><!-- end .form-body section -->
    <label style="padding: 5px;" for="another_field_1">another field 1 <input id="another_field_1" type="text" name="testinput1"></label><br>
    <label style="padding: 5px;" for="another_field_2">another field 2 <input id="another_field_2" type="text" name="testinput2"></label>
    <div class="form-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="button btn-primary"> Send Form </button>
    </div><!-- end .form-footer section -->
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        jQuery(".dropzone").dropzone({
            url: "upload.php",
            dictDefaultMessage: "Datei bitte hier ablegen!",
            success: function() {
                jQuery('.success-mark').show();
                jQuery('.error-mark').hide();
            },
            error: function() {
                jQuery('.success-mark').hide();
                jQuery('.error-mark').show();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the dropzone script, and see what you get then?

Comment: without dropzone it became a working form. $_FILES ist filled.